# compare data in sql server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a sql sever database on 2 servers. The structure of it is the same on both. A problem that I have is that I want to copy data between both databases - but the problem is I need to drop and recreate all the constraints first.

Any quick and easy way to script the differences between both databases, regarding data?

Comment: If the structures are identicla, why would dropping and recreating constrainte be ncesary to copy between them. Surely valid data on one is valid data on the other, if you copy tables in the correct order.

Comment: Is your data supposed to be identical ? Are like syncing the databases from time to time ?

Comment: Confused with your question... Your problem is to migrate data or compare DB structure?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens it's not always intuitive to copy data in the right order, and gets complex if you have circular / self-references, are merging with existing data, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, stop spending hours and hours trying to write a script that does this. Use a tried and true tool that handles all of that effort and debugging for you:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

There is a trial edition and there are several alternatives as well. Read this to see why you shouldn't re-invent the wheel:

http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing my 2 cents in. If you have Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate, you can actually use feature called "[Data Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833428%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" to compare data between two databases. And it will be able to generate update script for target database as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can only repeat the same opinion as Aaron Bertrand has, and to add to that, I had success using [XSQL](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/) for this kind of task.

As far as I remember, it was a nice, consistent tool to use...

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to turn the constraints off by altering the table in question such as:
   alter table [table name] nocheck constraint all

Then you could query from the other server by linking or query directly using the following format:
   select [cols] from [local table], [remote server.remote DB.remote table]